# Approximations to the Roots of a Function

Tags: approximation, roots, cubics

I want to find approximations to the root of a function in two variables using the Newton-Raphson method. I can use the method on a function in a single variable but I'm lost as to how you can use it when you have a function in two variables. The function I'm looking at is y^3+y +xy-x^3-2=0. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you have two variables and only one equation, there is an infinite number of solutions (as said by bubba) and I don't see what Newton-Raphson is doing here. PLease check if your post does not omit something.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any specific distinct "roots". The set of points $(x,y)$ where $y^3+y +xy-x^3-2=0$ is an entire curve in the $xy$ plane. Here's what the curve looks like:

[image: graph of y^3+y +xy-x^3-2=0]

You have to decide which point of that curve you want, by providing a second equation, for example. Then you can use Newton's method to solve for $x$ and $y$.

If you don't care which point of the curve you get, then $(1,1)$ is a nice one.